# How to be productive in a GWT Maven multi module project

Tags: gwt, maven-2, module, maven

I've got a big multi module Maven project where a small part is a web GUI made in GWT. I'm using  but I'm not sure on how to make my development efficient.

Right now I'm running hosted mode when developing stuff that's in the GWT project, and if I change something here it, I'm able to see the changes instantly when reloading the page. But if something is changed in the maven modules that holds most of the backend logic, I need to do `mvn:install` on the whole project structure, and the do a `gwt:run` to launch the hosted mode again. Very time consuming...

I've tried to follow the instructions here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/project.html#Multi-project_setup but it doesn't work as expected.

Is it possible to instantly see the changes made in dependent maven modules, and if so - how should the pom files be written?

Comment: if you are happy with one of the answers please accept it as valid. thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in being able to do this -- from what I've read here and elsewhere it seems like my odds of getting a multi-module maven setup to be productive with GWT are not fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Eclipse and [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) you can configure your project to [resolve dependencies from workspace](http://www.sonatype.com/books/m2eclipse-book/reference/dependencies.html#dependencies-sect-resolving-dependencies). To quote from the m2eclipse manual:

> You can configure a project to resolve dependencies from a workspace. This has the effect of altering the way that Maven locates dependency artifacts. If a project is configured to resolve dependencies from the workspace, these artifacts do not need to be present in your local repository

With this setup it there is no need to call `mvn:install` on related modules. I have been using this setup in combination with [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) to get instant reloading of classes across multi-module maven projects for quite a while now.

Comment: I've been using JRebel on other projects before, and it usually works perfectly fine. But I haven't got it to work in a convenient way when mixing it with GWT in a separate Maven module. Do you have any experience when dealing with GWT and JRebel?

Comment: I've been using Apache Wicket for the last 1.5 years and it works perfectly with Maven and JRebel. I also tried it with Vaadin which builds upon GWT but I have never used it in a GWT-only application.

Comment: Well, you've got a good point, but it doesn't seem to work properly with GWT. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. All my server code is being watched by JRebel, but when it comes to all code in the GWT project, nothing is being watched by JRebel for changes. I've got a rebel.xml generated by Maven in all my projects (I guess this is the way to go). So I'm still not happy with my project setup, and that's why you're answer hasn't been accepted yet.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving dependencies from the workspace doesnt work for me.

My solution : manually add the backend project dependency to the run configuration.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? I don't get what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The associated maven sub-modules are library dependencies that have to be in the WEB-INF/lib directory. The reason you have to do a mvn:install at the top-level is that you have to regenerate the jar when its building the associated sub-module, then have it copied into the WEB-INF/lib directory when the packaging for the war project occurs.

If you can come up with a way to make your IDE or some other tool auto-update the JAR in the WEB-INF/lib directory, then you should be good. You might try having your IDE auto-compile your associated project as an exploded JAR structure under the WEB-INF/lib directory. It will depend on your Web container whether this will be picked up or not. I think Tomcat would probably be ok with this, but I'm not sure about Jetty. I'm going to try this myself shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i have created a "proxy" plugin to the gwt-maven-plugin.

You can check it out here
https://github.com/xptdev/modgwt-maven-plugin